# How to set default par.settings theme in lattice

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

For example:

```
mytheme <- trellis.par.get()
mytheme$strip.border$col = 'grey80'
mytheme$strip.background$col = 'grey80'
mytheme$axis.line$col = 'grey80'
mytheme$axis.text$col = 'grey60'
mytheme$plot.symbol$pch = 20
mytheme$plot.symbol$cex = .5
mytheme$plot.symbol$col = '#7AC5CD'
mytheme$plot.symbol$alpha = .8

l.sc <- update(scatter.lattice, par.settings = mytheme,
               layout = c(3, 2),
               between = list(x = 0.3, y = 0.3))
print(l.sc)
```

How can I set the default of `par.settings` to be `mytheme`?

---

In the book **Lattice Multivariate Data Visualization with R** , page 131, the author gives this example:

```
lattice.options(lattice.theme = standard.theme("pdf"))
```

But I don't see how to adapt it to the current case. I tried:

```
lattice.options(lattice.theme = mytheme)
```

and it doesn't work.

Comment: There's a latticeOptions function, perhaps not with that exact spelling.

Comment: yeah, it's lattice.options, but the manpage is not clear at all.

Comment: By looking at the output of `lattice.options()`, it mostly has to do with layout.

Answer (score 4):

The theme can be set persistently (i.e., they will affect all subsequent plots until a new
setting is specified) using the `trellis.par.set()`function:

```
 trellis.par.set(mytheme) ## mythme is a named list with settings parameters
```

where mytheme is a list( no need to call  trellis.par.get()):

```
mytheme <- list()
mytheme$strip.border$col = 'grey80'
mytheme$strip.background$col = 'grey80'
mytheme$axis.line$col = 'grey80'
mytheme$axis.text$col = 'grey60'
mytheme$plot.symbol$pch = 20
mytheme$plot.symbol$cex = .5
mytheme$plot.symbol$col = '#7AC5CD'
mytheme$plot.symbol$alpha = .8
```

To set the theme temporarily , you set the "par.settings" argument  of the lattice
plotting function. For example this is how `latticeExtra` set the ggplot2 like theme:

```
library(latticeExtra) 
xyplot(exp(1:10) ~ 1:10, type = "b", 
       par.settings = ggplot2like())
```

Comment: Cool. I am trying to add this into .Rprofile, but the `trellis.par.get()` function fires up a window every time it's called, any way to suppress it?

Comment: `trellis.par.set(mytheme)` also pops up a window.

Comment: @qed yes. this will open the default device if it is not already open. You can use the second method to avoid this.

Comment: Is there any elegant way to make plotting parameter persistent (i.e. between R sesstions)? For example, I'd like to permantly change the default trellis color. Using `trellis.par.set` in `.Rprofile` works, but leads to popping window on startup.